# t_comment vim only works with vim-command not the gc prefix

Tags: vimrc, neovim

I'm sorry, I'm noob in vim but how to comment with [tcomment_vim](https://github.com/tomtom/tcomment_vim)? Here the debug info and some videos.

```
TCOMMENT: &ft = javascript => javascript
TCOMMENT: stx = jsString => javascriptString
TCOMMENT: ct  = {'rxmid': '', 'rxend': '', 'commentstring': '// %s', 'commentstring_rx': '\%%(// %s\|/* %s */\)', 'mode': '', 'filetype': 'javascript', 'replacements': {'*/': {'subst': '|)}>#', 'guard_rx': '^\s*/\?\*'}, '/*': {'subst': '#<{(|', 'guard_rx': '^\s*/\?\*'}}, 'rxbeg': '\*\+'}
```

Videos showing use of `gcc` [on insert mode](https://streamable.com/rs22jj).

But if I use, `:TComment` on the `vim-command-terminal` it works like charm. Only the shortcut, I can't use it.

And the last one, what is {motion} on the documentation of tcomment? `gc{motion}`

Note :
- I install it using `vim-plug`

## Update

`:map gc` result :

```
x  gc            <Plug>TComment_gc
n  gcb           <Plug>TComment_gcb                                                                                                                                                                      
n  gcc           <Plug>TComment_gcc
n  gc9c          <Plug>TComment_gc9c
n  gc9           <Plug>TComment_gc9
n  gc8c          <Plug>TComment_gc8c
n  gc8           <Plug>TComment_gc8
n  gc7c          <Plug>TComment_gc7c
n  gc7           <Plug>TComment_gc7
n  gc6c          <Plug>TComment_gc6c
n  gc6           <Plug>TComment_gc6
n  gc5c          <Plug>TComment_gc5c
n  gc5           <Plug>TComment_gc5
n  gc4c          <Plug>TComment_gc4c
n  gc4           <Plug>TComment_gc4
n  gc3c          <Plug>TComment_gc3c
n  gc3           <Plug>TComment_gc3
n  gc2c          <Plug>TComment_gc2c
n  gc2           <Plug>TComment_gc2
n  gc1c          <Plug>TComment_gc1c
n  gc1           <Plug>TComment_gc1
n  gc            <Plug>TComment_gc
```

Comment: If you run `:map gc`, what does Vim show you? Does `gc_` work (with an underscore)? How about `gcj`?

Comment: @filbranden Updated add map gc, `gc_` move the cursor to start of line, `gcj` move the cursor 1 line to bottom, I think there are a problem with my gc

Comment: Does `gcc` work in the first character of the line? Like `^gcc`?

Comment: @filbranden Nope it's also not working. I wonder why I tried other commenter too but fail https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary, here a full list of my Nvim config if you wonder https://github.com/mandaputtra/dotfiles/tree/master/nvim

Comment: I'll recommend [How do I debug my vimrc file?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/18609) to see if you can narrow down why this isn't working... I was going to recommend trying tpope's vim-commentary, but looks like you've done that already... It might be something related to the `gc` prefix, though looking at your vimrc or maps you listed, I can't really tell what it might be...

Comment: @filbranden thanks I'll do that. I'll update my question later if there are some issue, I'll just reset all plugins right now, and try minimal configuration again to see if its working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that  `set timeoutlen=100` on my `.vimrc` configuration file was the culprit it makes prefix `gc` can't be used for now I'm not sure enough why, and I don't know why. Maybe because I don't type fast enough.

## Edit :

To make clear here turns out that removing `set timeoutlen` actually make my `vim_which_key` open later that I could make some key combination with gc. So I remove `set timeoutlen` and its working altough the `vim_which_key` will open up after 1 second waiting, not a big deal, but I love commenting with keystroke then using `vim_which_key`

Comment: I have `set timeoutlen=1000 ttimeoutlen=0`, can you please elaborate why `timeoutlen` was the culprit?

Comment: https://github.com/mandaputtra/dotfiles/commit/a88cbec5702be1db0a73f79120cfff7429b3fc46#diff-3a4d7e1bc931fc725d2f2f13db412463 I still don't know yet. But for now my vim_which_key plugins are nt working because I remove the `set timeoutlen`. I think it because I copy pasta another vim person .vimrc. SO i don't know what when wrong.